# Error: No conduit initiator was found

Tags: soap, mule

currently I am working with SOAP service and Mule ESB.

But my SOAP service always return following error:

> No conduit initiator was found for the namespace http://ae7.iuk.fraport.de/esb/soap/bindings/esbp.. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: UebermittleAusweisdatenRequest

Here is the full stacktrace:

[image: Error]

What is the caused of those error? And how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty.jar to lib/user like this post suggests? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611803/cxf-2-4-2-no-conduit-initiator-was-found-for-the-namespace-http-schemas-xmlso

Comment: yes i have. But it still did not work.