# Java CXF HTTPS Client error

Tags: java, spring, apache, cxf

I have searched and searched and tried several different solutions I've found on the internet including this website. However, my problem persists. I'm trying to write a CXF (3.0.2) https client using a spring configuration. No matter what I try I keep getting the following error:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: No conduit initiator was found for the namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
```

I've surmised this means my CXF is not initialized properly, but I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've followed the CXF guide and examples. Here is my Spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
  xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
  xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
  xmlns:test123="http://example.com/XXX/ServiceDefinition/WSDLServiceClient/TestJunctionImpl" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
      http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/core 
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd                 
      http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

  <http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">

    <http:tlsClientParameters>
      <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="password">
        <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password"
                      file="my/file/dir/Morpit.jks"/>
      </sec:keyManagers>
      <sec:trustManagers>
        <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password"
                      file="my/file/dir/Truststore.jks"/>
      </sec:trustManagers>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
    <http:authorization>
      <sec:UserName>username</sec:UserName>
      <sec:Password>password</sec:Password>
    </http:authorization>
    <http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive"/>

  </http:conduit>

    <jaxws:client id="testJunctionJaxWSBean"
          serviceClass="com.example.service.client.TestJunction"
          address="https://example.com:19000/XXX/Services/TestJunction"
          serviceName="test123:TestJunctionImpl" 
          endpointName="test123:TestJunctionEndpoint">
    </jaxws:client>

</beans>
```

I do not have a cxf.xml on my classpath. Do I need one? I've included everything in the spring config as noted by the Apache config guide.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: where did you place the file?

Comment: I don't have one at all. I added this import to my spring config file <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>. The other thing I should mention is that I'm running on JBoss EAP 6. There appear to be some classloader issues.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611803/cxf-2-4-2-no-conduit-initiator-was-found-for-the-namespace-http-schemas-xmlso . Maybe one of the answers of this post helps you out.