# CXF ignores header argument from WebParam annotation

Tags: java, web-services, soap, annotations, cxf

I have generated code with `wsdl2java` which works fine with default Java `JAX-WS` implementation. When I add CXF my application stops working. I know that this because switching `JAX-WS` implementation( [Why wsdl2java generated code use CXF dependencies at will?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570430)).

I was debugging what is specific reason of failure and I found out that all my parameters are sent in message body. This is odd because it looks like CXF ignores `header = true` argument. Just like this:

```
@WebParam(name = "auth", targetNamespace = "urn:ns", header = true)
```

**Why is that so? What might be the reason?**

**Secondary question:**

I think that debugging annotation processing might help me. I've read some articles about that, but I don't know where I can find annotation processor for `@WebParam`. Any ideas? Any additional hints?

Answer (score 1):

We had the exact same issue. How is your CXF endpoint defined? Apparently you have a `wsdlURL` attribute defined, pointing to the wsdl. You should remove that.

Ours was something like this:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint
    id="upsTrackEndpoint"
    address="${ups.service.endpoint.track}"
    wsdlURL="wsdl/Track.wsdl"
    serviceClass="com.ups.wsdl.xoltws.track.v2.TrackPortType">
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

We changed it into this:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint
    id="upsTrackEndpoint"
    address="${ups.service.endpoint.track}"
    serviceClass="com.ups.wsdl.xoltws.track.v2.TrackPortType">
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

It seems that when you define the `wsdlURL` property, the `header` attribute is completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of your CXF-related JAR dependencies, then use the JARs defined here instead: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-cxf-with-maven.html

It should solve the problem.